# Open remote URL returns empty string?

Tags: ruby, json, curl, spotify, open-uri

I was using the following code snippet, which was working, to fetch the JSON response from the [Spotify oEmbed API](https://embed.spotify.com/oembed/?url=http://open.spotify.com/album/5Mxj65mCzxUjDkoqz7JXPJ).

I was doing this:

```
response = JSON.parse(open("https://embed.spotify.com/oembed/?url=http://open.spotify.com/album/5Mxj65mCzxUjDkoqz7JXPJ").read)
```

But now, this stopped working because:

```
2.0.0p247 :017 > open("https://embed.spotify.com/oembed/?url=http://open.spotify.com/album/5Mxj65mCzxUjDkoqz7JXPJ").read
 => ""
```

But, using cURL, I get:

```
$curl https://embed.spotify.com/oembed/\?url\=http://open.spotify.com/album/5Mxj65mCzxUjDkoqz7JXPJ
{"provider_url":"https:\/\/www.spotify.com","version":"1.0","thumbnail_width":300,"height":380,"thumbnail_height":300,"title":"Illum Sphere - 13. Embryonic","width":300,"thumbnail_url":"https:\/\/d3rt1990lpmkn.cloudfront.net\/cover\/d4f5d8624752eeae3dc8bc3d58e2155d095181c1","provider_name":"Spotify","type":"rich","html":"<iframe src=\"https:\/\/embed.spotify.com\/?uri=spotify:album:5Mxj65mCzxUjDkoqz7JXPJ\" width=\"300\" height=\"380\" frameborder=\"0\" allowtransparency=\"true\"><\/iframe>"}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing the `User-Agent`:

```
require 'open-uri'
puts open("https://embed.spotify.com/oembed/?url=http://open.spotify.com/album/5Mxj65mCzxUjDkoqz7JXPJ", "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}").read
```

Result:

```
{"provider_url":"https:\/\/www.spotify.com","version":"1.0","thumbnail_width":300,"height":380,"thumbnail_height":300,"title":"
Illum Sphere - 13. Embryonic","width":300,"thumbnail_url":"https:\/\/d3rt1990lpmkn.cloudfront.net\/cover\/d4f5d8624752eeae3dc8b
c3d58e2155d095181c1","provider_name":"Spotify","type":"rich","html":"<iframe src=\"https:\/\/embed.spotify.com\/?uri=spotify:al
bum:5Mxj65mCzxUjDkoqz7JXPJ\" width=\"300\" height=\"380\" frameborder=\"0\" allowtransparency=\"true\"><\/iframe>"}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But do you have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Not entirely sure. Since it was working before (as you stated), I can only assume that now they are enforcing some type `user-agent` validation (from curl you are implicitly sending one, i.e `User-Agent: curl/7.30.0` for example ). That, off course, is just a wild guess.

Comment: That's a very valid guess. It's considered bad form to make requests to sites without identifying your code, whether spidering or using an API. Give them something to identify you so they can contact you if your code misbehaves; That beats being banned entirely.